# Distance of the stave lines?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, engraving

I have not found definite answers for these two doubts, can anyone help me?

- At what distance should the stave lines be?
- What distance should be between staves?

Comment: You won't find a definitive answer because it depends. I would research the intended ensemble or musicians and see what they want. For example, major concert orchestras are likely to prefer the MOLA guidelines, orchestras for scoring film and TV will have very different standards, bands will use another set of standards, chamber ensembles will have their own preferences, etc.

Comment: Related: [Standard staff size](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61870/standard-staff-size?)

Comment: What size paper are you using?  Is it a part or a score?  If a part, it it for a singer or an instrumentalist?  If it is a score, how many staves are in each system?  The answer depends on all of these factors and probably more.

Answer (score 2):

The distances depend on the type of score being produced.

The standard reference for all things notation related is *Behind Bars* by Elaine Gould (Faber, 2011). Page 483 includes a table of staff sizes according to purpose. For example

- Full score, staff height = 3.7mm
- Single-stave parts, piano music, songs = 6.5mm or 7mm.

For the distance between staves, Gould indicates that

> Staves should be at least a stave height apart. (p. 488, "Distance between Staves")

and

> When a page contains more than one system, the distance between systems should, if possible, be greater than the distance between the most widely spaced staves on an adjacent system. (p. 488, "Distance between Staves")

The book is quite detailed and extensive in describing staff size and distance according to musical context (e.g., instrument types, number of instruments, alignment across pages, etc.), so it's recommended to obtain a copy to find the details specific to the situation at hand. Most libraries containing a music section should have a copy.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn’t hold it that strictly. Back in the day of traditional pewter plate engraving the rastral height would have been determined by the sets of stencils used. As each publisher had their own stencils and there is no actual industry norm for engraving stencils there are lots of variations, so I would take these as a general reference rather than a strict rule.

Comment: If I bought a Blank Sheet Music Notebook, for writing music, what would the above distances be?

Comment: @user94924 it depends on what kind of notebook it is and on who printed it.

Comment: You might suggest looking more precisely at the intended audience for the printed music. For example, the [MOLA guidelines](https://mola-inc.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/mola3/MOLA-Guidelines-for-Music-Preparation.pdf) say "The minimum legible staff size for scores is 4 mm", so they want slightly bigger staves than Gould recommends, and anyone producing scores for a major orchestra would be wise to consider MOLA's guidelines over Gould's.

Comment: Although Gould's book is a very good reference (bought one a while ago!) I've used, and still use, different sizes sometimes even enlarging certain music for ease of reading. So, I don't believe there is an 'industry standard' for this, world wide.

Comment: Gould recommends >6.5mm for parts, but in practice anything less than 7mm is hard to read for anybody over 30.

Answer (score 1):

Staff height and the distance between them  is always a compromise between legibilty and putting as much music as possible on the page.
The minimum staff height is going to depend on the purpose of the music and how far away the player is going to be from the music.

MOLA (The Major Orchestra Librarian's Assocation) [Guidelines for Music Preparation](https://mola-inc.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/mola3/MOLA-Guidelines-for-Music-Preparation.pdf) recommend staff hights:

- full scores: at least 4mm
- wind parts at least 7mm
- other parts 7.5mm to 8.5mm

Educational music for children can be larger.

The distance between staves will depend on how much the music extends vertically on each one. If there are a of of very high notes and low notes, possibly with articulations and other markings then to  a lot more space between staves is needed, so the the low notes from one system don't get in the way of the high notes from the one below. The space between staves is going to influence how many systems fit on a page. For most types of part ten staves on a page (A4) is a good average. For very simple music twelve might fit. For very complicated music probably less than ten.
For pages with only a few systems, most notation programs offer an option to space the staves equally over the page. Don't do this, it makes the music harder to read,

Comment: Why smaller for winds?  It seems that they're recommending the same larger size for both brass and strings.  I can see why a trombonist might need to be farther from the stand than an oboist, because of the slide, and strings, obviously, because they share, but trumpets?  Horns?  It's intriguing.  Do you know why?

Comment: @phoog Orchestral wind players play one to a part, strings two to a part so they're farther away. Percussion players mostly need to be farther from the music because they have instruments in the way.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the [default staff height in LilyPond is 20 points](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/setting-the-staff-size), which is about 7 mm†. The font that generates the glyphs comes in versions intended for staves of the range of 3.9 mm – 8.9 mm

The vertical distances between staves and systems are flexible based on context, and of course everything in LilyPond is adjustable.

I checked a couple blank staff notebooks I had on hand and found:

Carl Fischer AC112, 12 staves per page: about 8 mm height, 12 mm spacing.

Mel Bay MB93694, 12 staves per page: about 9 mm height, 13.5 mm spacing (larger pages than the Carl Fischer).

The back cover of the Mel Bay notebook lists other manuscript products. There are student books with as few as 5 staves per page.  This suggests a much larger spacing (just as you would expect on lined writing paper intended for children), but the page size isn't listed so it's impossible to guess exactly the staff height or spacing.

---

†LilyPond uses [American points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#American_points), AKA TeX points(1/72.27 inch), not [Desktop publishing points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#Desktop_publishing_point), AKA PostScript points of 1/72 in.)